# Insert element into BinaryTree recursively

Tags: c++, pointers, recursion, binary-tree

I have attempted to write the following method recursively to insert a node into a binary tree. The strategy was to basically insert the node in any NULL left or right pointers.

```
typedef struct BinaryTreeNode {
int data;
BinaryTreeNode * left;
BinaryTreeNode * right;
} BinaryTreeNode;

void InsertElementInBinaryTree(BinaryTreeNode *root, BinaryTreeNode *element) {
    if(root) {
         if(root -> left == NULL) root -> left = element;
         else if(root -> right == NULL) root -> right = element;
         InsertElementInBinaryTree(root -> left, element);
         InsertElementInBinaryTree(root -> right, element);
    }
}
```

The method is called as follows in the main function

`InsertElementInBinaryTree(&root , new BinaryTreeNode{8, NULL,NULL});`

The issue is that this call always returns a segmentation fault error so I believe the error is in the recursion ?

Comment: When using dynamic structures such as linked-lists and trees you have to use **malloc()** to reserve storage on the heap, before you can store any data.  You also have to **free()** it before the application exits, otherwise repeated use of your application will make all heap memory unusable.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing some conditions:

```
     if (root->data > element->data) {
         if (root->left == NULL) {
             root->left = element;
         } else {
             InsertElementInBinaryTree(root->left, element);
         }
     } else {
         if (root->right == NULL) {
             root->right = element;
         } else {
         InsertElementInBinaryTree(root->right, element);
          }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to implement binary tree then for any current node all the nodes from the left subtree should have lower `data` than the `data` in current node and all the `data` from the right subtree should be greater.

```
void InsertElementInBinaryTree(BinaryTreeNode *&root, BinaryTreeNode *element) {
     if(root == NULL) { root = element; return;}
     if(root -> data > element -> data) 
         InsertElementInBinaryTree(root->left, element);
     else
         InsertElementInBinaryTree(root->right, element);
}
```

So actually `data` values define the position `element` will inserted at. Also I'm passing `BinaryTreeNode *&root` as a reference in order the `root` pointer to be modifiable.

Usage:

```
// declare root
BinaryTreeNode* root;
// insertion, no & operator before root
InsertElementInBinaryTree(root, new BinaryTreeNode{8, NULL,NULL});
```

Answer (score 0):

The function can look the following way

```
void InsertElementInBinaryTree( BinaryTreeNode * &root, int data ) 
{
    if ( root == nullptr )
    {
        root = new BinaryTreeNode { data, nullptr, nullptr };
    }
    else if ( data < root->data )
    {
        InsertElementInBinaryTree( root->left, data );
    }
    else
    {
        InsertElementInBinaryTree( root->right, data );
    }
}
```

and called like

```
InsertElementInBinaryTree( root , 8 );
```

and the object `root` should be defined initially like

```
BinaryTreeNode *root = nullptr;
```